# Fix bad encoding in Firefox in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: firefox, kubuntu, google-chrome, icons

This time I have a question to which maybe some of you may find trivial (hopefully!).

I'm running Firefox 30.0 in Kubuntu 14.04 (fresh install) and I'm having a weird problem, in some sites some symbols/logos/icons are showing terrible wrong

I'm suspecting something related to encoding but I'm not really sure.

I hope some of you have some ideas to fix this.

The icons look like this:
[ [image]

and should look like this:
[ [image]

Comment: Could you please include the link. Also a screen shot, showing how wrong it is, would give a representation what issue you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks Ruslan, I'm trying to do it right now! just a second.

Comment: Here's the sample: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/391635/Bad%20Icons%20on%20FF.png 

This is how its supposed to look: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/391635/Icons%20well%20displayed%20on%20hrome.png

Comment: Those are likely text icons using @font-face embedded fonts instead of images - have you tried disabling the extensions in Firefox? (half of mine block things like this (as well as ads - intentionally))

Comment: Thanks @Wilf I've just did that (disable all add-ons) given you recommendation and restarted FF, the page still looks the same.

Comment: Could you please check `Preferences > Options > Content : Fonts & Colors > Advanced: [X] "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above"`

Comment: Great! @RuslanGerasimov, that dis the trick! thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, I put in answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check

```
Preferences > Options > Content : Fonts & Colors > Advanced: [X] "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a preferences setting you may need to get the fonts to work.

Go to 'Preferences' > 'Content', then under 'Fonts & Colours' click 'Advanced' - enable 'Allow pages to pick their own fonts', close the settings and reload the page.

With it disabled:
[image]

With it enabled:
[image]